# Unix time conversion with Momentjs return wrong day?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, unix-timestamp

This is probably a quick fix but I can't find a straightforward answer in the Momentjs docs. I am converting Unix time to "normal" time, but getting the previous day instead of the actual day it should be. For example, converting `1467331201` should return July 01, 2016, but I'm getting June 30, 2016. When I convert using an online converter, I get the correct date. My hunch is that there is some issue with time zones: the data was generated in New York (EST), but I'm working in Honolulu (HST). I am 5/6 hours behind, so midnight in New York would still be the previous day here. Any thoughts on how to control for time zone?

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/timezone-offset/

Comment: Thanks, Marc B. That function is deprecated from 2.9.0+, but those docs led me to the new function and then to `.utc()`, which I ended up using successfully. For anyone who's is interested in the final: `moment.unix(d.created_at).utc()`